# Iron Router layout for notFoundTemplate

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I understand that using iron router, a notFound template can be set like this:

```
Router.configure({
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
})
```

However this only sets the TEMPLATE for "notFound" routes. What if I wanted to set a custom layout for notFound routes? Is this possible? The doc mentions nothing about this and as far as I can see the configure() function only accepts a template name.

Comment: You can use the [dataNotFound](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#plugins) plugin. You just need to return false from the `data` function in your router and it will use the template.